How can I make curtains retract better on an adjustable curtain rod?
I have adjustable curtain rods that look similar to this.

That gap in the middle where the rod is adjusted constantly snags my curtains. It can be pretty difficult to actually move them along the rod. I've tried adding some tape to smooth over the gap, but it doesn't help much.
What else can I try to adjust this gap? It needs to be fully removable so that I can adjust the rod in the future if I need to. Ideally it will not be very visible from my black curtain rods, but I'll take whatever solution works.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

@RMDman is there a more appropriate site for it to be migrated to? I wasn't sure where else to put it

Installing curtains and getting them to function the way you want is not home improvement?

@Jay, No, this is a decorating question.

He's not asking for help choosing colors.  This isn't the "Rough In Stack Exchange".   Are painting questions off topic?

They should not need adjusting after being placed, unless moving every few months.  Unless the house moves, but then you have bigger problems.

get a plastic shower curtain rod cover and cut a section to fit the gap ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=shower+curtain+rod+cover&iax=images&ia=images

Those rods are not meant for curtains that will normally travel along the rod.  They are meant for curtains that stay put, or that pull back without sliding to hang over a holdback.  They get used in your situation because it's easy, but as you've seen they are annoying.
To solve your problem you can:

Get a solid rod that you cut to size instead of a retractable one.
Use ball-bearing curtain hooks.  (They have a bunch of beads on the top part of the hook).   These are not great, they don't totally solve the problem, they don't look good and they make noise.  But they solve the problem a little bit.
Get a proper curtain rod with a trolley, wheels, string, etc.
I had a shower curtain rod once, retractable like yours, but the gasket between the inner and outer rods was made of teflon and it was wedge-shaped.  It came to a point along the smaller part of the rod instead of presenting a ridge.  The actual product was still annoying, it wasn't wedge-shaped enough and it solved the problem ... a little bit.  But you could look for a product like that if you really need to adjust it frequently.  (But why?)  Or if you're very handy you could make something like that.  Maybe 3D-print it?
[added later] turns out you don't have to make it. Just look up and buy "curtain rod slide tape".   That's it.


If the annoyance factor justifies the additional expense, buy another identical curtain rod and cut a length of outer tube that will exactly cover the exposed length of inner tube, and slip it over the inner tube to make one continuous outer tube with a parting line.
With no change in diameter, there should be no more snagging.
